# Launcher activity not starting

Tags: android, android-manifest

My launcher activity not starting can any body tell me whats the problem.

I also have a service in it.
Any help is appreciated Please help i am stuck and don't know what to do.

Here is  the code of **Manifest**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pelicans.abc.abc">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".Permiss"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable">
        </meta-data>
    </activity>


    <service
        android:name=".Service.FeatureService"
        android:enabled="true">
    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".Receiver.RestartService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="RestartServiceWhenStopped">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="Restart_Service"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Launcher activity is not called in any version of android.

Comment: post your error log please

Comment: i am not getting any error :(

Comment: thats not possible. try to debug and then check

Comment: did i miss something in manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :
I think remove this:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="Restart_Service"></action>
    </intent-filter>
```

//need to modified

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"  //it must contain package name and .searchable
        android:resource="@xml/searchable">
    </meta-data>
```

OR

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name=".Restart_Service"></action> //add dot
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. really no log?..try more times,try to Log at `application onCreate()` and `activity onCreate()`
2. delete sth,like your `MainActivity` or `RestartService`,and try again

Answer (score 0):

If launcher icon is working and launching from studio is not working, then disable Instant Run and try.